# Ignoring directory and all content underneath, clarification needed

Tags: git, gitignore

Files i want to ignore are in `my-client/target/surefire-reports/*.txt`

My `.gitignore` contains `*/surefire-reports/*.txt`, but ignore does not seem to be happening. When i `mvn install` new reports are created and test data appears in need of a commit.

Is my `.gitignore` incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the path in your .gitignore should work.

Were the files that mvn install is generating added to your git repository before adding the git ignore line? If so, take a look at [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

Comment: Originally, when i noticed the issue, yes. After that, i updated my `.gitignore` and ran a commit. Followed by `mvn install` the same issue with commit is seen. New content is generated and is uncommitted.

Comment: See info added, that should fix it